# Download a file from remote Linux to local Windows (user access at Linux machine with ssh; I cannot install software on Windows and no PuTTY)

Tags: linux, windows, remote-access, file-transfer

I have user access at Linux machine. I am able to connect to Linux machine with ssh from Windows machine and execute Linux commands.

I cannot install any software on Windows machine. I do not have PuTTY installed on on Windows machine.

**Question:** How to download a file from remote Linux machine to local Windows machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably get Filezilla portable which requires no installation ([here](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?show_all=1), use no-setup *.zip file according to your CPU architecture). Use your SSH credentials to connect and explicitly point to port 22.

Comment: This perfectly worked. Thank you.